# After creating tab bars and widgets the emulator gives such an error when opening the app

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

[image]

I could not transfer my code to the site as I wrote it, but I placed your photo Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to pass an uninitialized String to a Text-Widget (Naber). A Text-Widget can not handle uninitialized Strings which have the value null.

Therefore try initializing the String 'Naber' directly like:

```
String Naber = 'Some text';
```

This should work.